# Typescript's keyof with array of objects

Tags: arrays, typescript, types, keyof

I'm very new to typescript and having a hard time finding some extensive documentation on `keyof`. If you have

```
export interface someClassProps<T extends object> {

    /*
        Lets assume T look is an object that looks something like:

        T = {"name": "",
             "val": NaN,
             "active": false}
    */

    A: Array<T>;            // an array of objects
    B: keyof T;             // What type is this? Is just a type of object or is it the keys of T?
    C: keyof Array<T>[0];   // Is this the keys of T?
    D: keyof Array<T>       // Is this type object?
}
```

What type do you get for `B` or `C`? I'm hoping to get a type from `keyof` that is the would be `name | val | active`. Am I looking for an approach that looks like `B`, `C`, or something fully different?

Alternatively is there an easy way to print the types from `keyof`? That would allow me to just figure this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keyof` gives you the union type of the keys of the given type. So for example, if you had:

```
export SomeClass implements<{ name: string, val: number, active: boolean}>
```

...then `B` would be `"name" | "val" | "active"`. In this case, `C` would also be `"name" | "val" | "active"` since `Array<T>[0]` is 0th element of an array with elements of `T` which is just `T`.

Note that with the way TypeScript interfaces work, `implements` just means "check this implementation is assignable to the interface" and doesn't actually set the class types by default. This means you will still have to do `B: "name" | "val" | "active"` if you wanted. You could also just do `B: "name"` since that type is assignable to the union type of all the keys.

Comment: So this function is being used in a way that i don't know what the keys of the object are. Is `B` always guaranteed to be the same as `C` if `Array<T>` is an array of objects? Or is it keyof `Array<T>` just going to be of type object?

Comment: `keyof Array<T>` is different than `keyof Array<T>[0]` since the former would be the union type of all keys of `Array` including array methods. Otherwise it will be the `T` object.

Comment: Ah i see. So i've added a new type`D` to my example. In my example B and C are the same type, but D is not?

Comment: Type `D` would essentially be the union of `"includes" | "length" | "map"`, etc. i.e. you probably don't want to use that